# Why isn't my iFrame working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I can't under why the iFrame on the link page isn't displaying. Any ideas?

https://www.loveyourdoor.co.uk/truedor-builder

Thanks

Comment: http**s**://ww...

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score -1):

You have a CORS issue, the hosting page (domain loveyourdoor.co.uk) uses https protocol and references http site.
You should update IIS of the site truedordesigner.co.uk and allow hosting page to include this site by adding custom HTTP response headers key "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" with value "loveyourdoor.co.uk", or if you're using .NET, add this to web.config:

```
 <customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="loveyourdoor.co.uk" />
 </customHeaders>
```

Comment: Hi Dalibor, Thanks for the comment. I only have control over loveyourdoor.co.uk. I don't have access to truedordesigner.co.uk. Thanks

Comment: "You have a CORS issue, the hosting page (domain loveyourdoor.co.uk) uses https protocol and references http site." — That is a mixed content issue, not a Same Origin Policy violation. CORS would not help. CORS never helps with any problem relating to simply displaying content in an iframe.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. What is the solution to displaying a http iframe on a https page?